# Vlookup till the last col cell - VBA

Tags: vba, vlookup

I am performing a vlookup in the Col U(XXX) in cell U2 and I want to copy the vlookup formula till the last cell in the U column.

Below is the code which I am using :

```
Range("U1").Value = "XXX"
Range("U2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=VLOOKUP(RC[-1],'[XXX.xlsm]GLOBAL_HEADCOUNT_export'!C1:C32,30,0)"

Selection.End(xlDown).Select
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 21).Select (using 21 since its the U col)
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp)).Select
Selection.FillDown
```

However I am not able to perform the same. Can some one please help me here ?

Comment: Can some one suggest me a method to perform vlookup till the last cell of the col in excel using VBA

Answer (score 0):

I didn't check the **VLOOKUP** formula, but if you want to copy this formulas to Column U untill last existing cell in **Column U**, use the simple code below:

```
last_row = Cells(Rows.count, "U").End(xlUp).Row

Range("U1").Value = "XXX"  
Range("U2:U" & last_row).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-1],'[XXX.xlsm]GLOBAL_HEADCOUNT_export'!C1:C32,30,0)"
```

Comment: Shai, my col U is blank and hence I was using the offset method.. this is not working

Comment: @user1553562 in your post you requested to drag this formula down to last cell in _Column U_ , no ? where do you want to copy this formula to ? where is the range (Column) that the `VLOOKUP` is checking?